# Como abrir o teclado numérico num campo formatado?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um campo de texto que recebe o CPF, ele possui uma máscara de CPF, porém como é um campo texto, em Mobile ele não abre direto naquele teclado numérico e quando mudo o tipo dele para number, ele só escreve os 3 primeiros dígitos e apaga tudo quando chega no "." da formatação do campo.

```
<html>
    <div class="form-separador">
        <input type="text"  class="input1"  id="cpf" name="cpf"
               placeholder="000.000.000-00" value="%%=v(@Cpf)=%%" required >
    </div>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atualize a versão do maskinput para a versão 1.4.
Adicione type="tel" e remova o atributo maxlength da entrada ou defina-o como um valor certo para não interferir com a ação do cursor, como 20.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437478/4312593

Comment: Eu alterei o type do input "input type="tel"" no HTML, como disse. Dessa forma, ele passou a aceitar dígitos como "." ou "-" e ainda abre diretamente o campo numérico. Valeu!!!